# How to get document.referrer inside AMP page with <amp-script>?

Tags: javascript, amp-html, referrer, ampscript

I am trying to serve a banner for users coming from Google so I need a referrer to do this. I've managed to do it on normal pages but on AMP I can't get it to work since `document.referrer`  returns `undefined`.

Any ideas how to get it on an AMP page?

```
<amp-script width="200" height="100" script="hello-world">

</amp-script>

<script id="hello-world" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    console.log( document.referrer );
    // returns undefined on AMP page
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check this page: https://github.com/ampproject/worker-dom/blob/main/web_compat_table.md

Comment: Thanks, I  haven't seen this. This proves that it's not possible to find the referrer inside an amp page.

Comment: I may be wrong but have you tried using html parsing language for referrer eg: PHP  `<div id="doc-refer"><?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?></div>` inside `<amp-script>` and use it